# D3.js - How to highlight the biggest and smallest (minimum and max) columns in a bar chart?

Tags: d3.js, bar-chart

I'm a Designer just starting to fool around with some d3 tutorials and of course I just got stuck at some point. I was wondering which is the best way to highlight the biggest and smaller columns in a bar graph. I would like them to differ in colour, like "red" for the smaller "green" for the biggest. Anyone can help me out.

This is what i got so far:

```
<body>

<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var t = 1297110663, // start time (seconds since epoch)
      v = 70, // start value (subscribers)
      data = d3.range(30).map(next); // starting dataset

  function next() {
    return {
      time: ++t,
      value: v = ~~Math.max(10, Math.min(90, v + 10 * (Math.random() - .5)))
    };
 }

setInterval(function() {
   data.shift();
   data.push(next());
   redraw();
}, 1500);

 var w = 11,
       h = 120;

 var x = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, 1])
      .range([0, w]);

 var y = d3.scale.linear()
     .domain([0, 100])
     .range([0, h]);

 var chart = d3.select("body").append("svg")
     .attr("width", w * (data.length +3))
     .attr("height", h);

 chart.selectAll("rect")
     .data(data)
   .enter().append("rect")
     .attr("x", function(d, i) { return x(i) ; })
     .attr("y", function(d) { return h - y(d.value) - .5; })
     .attr("width", w)
     .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
     .style("fill", "#ccc")
     .style("stroke", "white")

chart.select("rect")
    .style("fill", "red");

 chart.append("line")
     .attr("x1", 0)
     .attr("x2", w * (data.length))
     .attr("y1", h - .5)
     .attr("y2", h - .5)
     .style("stroke", "black");

</script>
```

Many Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; });
```

along with the corresponding `d3.min` function to get your extent (there is also `d3.extent` which returns `[min, max]`).

Then you could say:

```
chart.select("rect")
  .filter(function(d) { return d.value === max; })
  .classed("max", true);
```

which will add the `max` class to any bar with the maximum value. Do the same for `min` and you're good.

Also you should be saving your selections like:

```
var bars = chart.selectAll("rect")
  .data(data);

//use later, like
bars.enter()...
bars.filter()...
```

Comment: Thanks @enjalot. I was able to figure out how to do it because of your comment. The olny thing I changed was actually using sellectAll("rect") instead of select("rect"). With select it worked only when the max and min were in the first position. `var max = d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value })
chart.selectAll("rect").filter(function(d) { return d.value === max }) 
      .classed("max", true)
      .attr("fill", "green")`